# Drawing text over Core Graphics in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, core-graphics

Background: I am drawing on a UIImageView with Core Graphics. I would like to ultimately draw a text string over the core graphics drawing.

[This (hackingwithswift.com)](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/core-graphics/how-to-draw-a-text-string-using-core-graphics) method i used to draw the text to an image, set my imageView to that image, and then draw over with core graphics. But I want the text to overlay the core graphics drawing.

Now I have moved to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35574171/6337391 but it still isnt allowing me to write on top of my drawing.

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    func drawScale() {
        // establish 6 points to draw a little bar with
        let length = CGFloat(80.0)
        let bottom = imageView.bounds.size.height - 15.0
        let left = CGFloat(20.0)
        let top = bottom - 20.0
        let middle = top + 10.0
        let right = left + length
        let topLeft = CGPoint(x: left, y: top)
        let topRight = CGPoint(x: right, y: top)
        let bottomRight = CGPoint(x: right, y: bottom)
        let bottomLeft = CGPoint(x: left, y: bottom)
        let middleLeft = CGPoint(x: left, y: middle)
        let middleRight = CGPoint(x: right, y: middle)

        // draw the bar
        drawLineFrom(fromPoint: topLeft, toPoint: bottomLeft, color: UIColor.red.cgColor, width: 1.0, alias: false)
        drawLineFrom(fromPoint: topRight, toPoint: bottomRight, color: UIColor.red.cgColor, width: 1.0, alias: false)
        drawLineFrom(fromPoint: middleLeft, toPoint: middleRight, color: UIColor.red.cgColor, width: 1.0, alias: false)

        // draw a text string
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageView.frame.size)

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

        let attrs = [
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12),
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red]

        let scaleString = "45 feet"
        scaleString.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 50), withAttributes: attrs)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }

    /* Stroke a line between two CGPoints. Color, width, anti-alias options. */
    func drawLineFrom(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint, color: CGColor, width: CGFloat, alias: Bool) {
        // 1
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageView.frame.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.setShouldAntialias(alias)
        self.imageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.imageView.frame.size.width, height: self.imageView.frame.size.height))

        // 2
        context.move(to: fromPoint)
        context.addLine(to: toPoint)

        // 3
        context.setLineWidth(width)
        context.setStrokeColor(color)

        // 4
        context.strokePath()

        // 5
        self.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        self.imageView.alpha = 1.0
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
}
```

Doesnt work. Drawing the text string completely erases the bar. If move the bar drawing code under the string drawing code, then both are visible, but of course the bar is then over the string.

Comment: Could you create your text in a CATextLayer and add it to the image view?

Comment: What do you mean by "I am drawing on a UIImageView with Core Graphics", and under what class are you running your code?

Comment: I added a little bit of contextualizing code, hope it helps. I think the answer is going to lie in Core Text, I am going to try and find a solution down that road myself. Things like [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052665/swift-playground-core-graphics-core-text-custom-view) look promising

Answer (score 24):

Using Swift 4:

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

let attributes = [
    NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
    NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0),
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue
]

let myText = "HELLO"
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: myText, attributes: attributes)

let stringRect = CGRect(x: W/2 - 50, y: border, width: 100, height: H)
attributedString.draw(in: stringRect)
```

For Swift 4.2, change the above `attributes` to:

```
let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
    .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
    .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0),
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue
]
```

Comment: swift 4.2 `NSAttributedString.Key.xxx`

Comment: Can I ask what the advantages are to draw texts rather than to use the UILabel? Sorry I'm new to Swift

Comment: if you are un custom views you cannot use UIlabel.

Answer (score 4):

> Swift 3.0 : to draw text

```
   func drawMyText(myText:String,textColor:UIColor, FontName:String, FontSize:CGFloat, inRect:CGRect){

     let textFont = UIFont(name: FontName, size: FontSize)!
    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
        ] as [String : Any]

    myText.draw(in: inRect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
}
```

> call this function , below is e.g.

```
let _rect = CGRect(x: 40, y: 100, width: 40, height: 40)

 drawMyText(myText: "Hello", textColor: UIColor.black, FontName: "Helvetica Bold", FontSize: 11 , inRect:_rect)
```

Comment: That only differs from my code in that you removed the  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageView.frame.size) . Your code does not draw any text in my case.

Comment: Put drawMyText function in uiview subclass and call it from drawrect function, please let me know if you need further help

Comment: My problem is that drawing text erases what i drew before. In my example above, the text will appear but it completely erases the lines I drew previously. As far as I can tell, your only suggesting that I draw text in a rect rather than at a point, which is not doing anything for me.

Comment: Small text. I want to draw text as image size