# How to add Text to an NSView on MacOS in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, text, nsview

Wondering what the correct way is to add non-editable text to an NSView for MacOS using Swift. I am not sure if I am supposed to [draw it like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42498721/drawing-text-over-core-graphics-in-swift-3), or if there is another way. I am used to HTML where you just set the textContent property on an element/view and that's it. Not sure if it should be at the level of the canvas/cgrect or UITextView or what.

Basically I would like to add both button labels (small amounts of text) and paragraphs of text (large amounts) using the same approach if possible, using something that has good performance.

Comment: There isn't a one size fits all correct way. Is this an app using a storyboard? Did you try using standard controls like `NSButton` and `NSTextView`?

Comment: No this isn't using storyboard. I could try NSTextView, but I'm just not sure if that's too  "heavyweight"

Comment: `NSTextField` is simpler.